# the object variable in link list reverse codes

Tags: variables, object

Hi this is a link list reverse code.  Anyone can help me understand that the differecen between  r = Solution().reverseList(**n1**)   and  r = Solution().reverseList(**ListNode(1)**).

I wonder why the output which is [1] and [3,2,1] respectively and what is the purpose of to assign the ListNode object to a variable.

```
class Solution(object):
def reverseList(self, head):
    """
    :type head: ListNode
    :rtype: ListNode
    """
    #if not head:
    #   return None
    prev = head
    curr = prev.next
    while curr:
        next =curr.next
        curr.next = prev
        prev = curr
        curr = next
    head.next = None
    return prev




class ListNode(object):
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.val = x
        self.next = None
    def to_list(self):
        return[self.val] + self.next.to_list() if self.next else [self.val]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    n1 = ListNode(1)
    n2 = ListNode(2)
    n3 = ListNode(3)
    n1.next = n2
    n2.next = n3
    r = Solution().reverseList(n1)
    print r.to_list()
    #assert r.to_list() == [3,2,1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I understood now.

ListNode(1) has no "next" set, so it will forever return 1 as it's list, whereas n1 starts the same way (as just node of 1), but the "next" attribute is set to node of 2 whose "next" is set to node of 3, so n1 carries all of this information with it, and ListNode(1) does not.

welcome any comments.